# CodeIgniter Routing - changing to handle a subdomain?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

I have my site built in CodeIgniter.  The url format is

```
domain.com/lang/id/descriptive-text
```

e.g.

```
domain.com/en/12/article-on-codeigniter-routing
```

One particular page (Tours) has all of the tour information (retrieved according to id number) to display.  HOWEVER, i now have a booking system written in Ruby on Rails that i need to integrate. The way to do that is going to have to be have a subdomain called booking.domain.com and each tour page to display on that subdomain so that the in page booking system can run properly.

That means coding the Tours page in ruby and passing in the info from codeigniter.  The way i know whether a page is a Tour or just other pages is that the Tour pages have id greater than 20 but less than 40.

Below is my current routing code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "content";
$route['en/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/en/$1";
$route['de/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/de/$1";
$route['es/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/es/$1";
$route['it/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/it/$1";
```

My question is how would i change this to now reflect this new change??  I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you going to host both CodeIgntier and Ruby applications under same sub domain?

Comment: No the codeigniter will be on the main domain https://example.com and then the Ruby application will be on https://subdomain.example.com.

Comment: If I am not wrong, You need to show your Codeigniter website content under the Ruby Booking Portal and also you need to keep the current codeigniter website in main domain as well. am I correct?

Comment: main website will have codeigniter and then when they click on a product, the product page will be on a subdomain written in ruby which contains the booking system.  so codigniter for example.com and ruby on rails for bookings.example.com

Comment: So you want to redirect to the subdomain or show the subdomain content within the main domain?

Comment: i dont see how i can display the subdomain content in the main domain.  I think i have to redirect to the subdomain (although look and feel will be the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution** (without modifying the CodeIgniter)

Use .htaccess to do the redirection.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^([^/]+)/([20][0-9]|[30][0-9]|[40]+)/([^/]+)?$    http://sub.maindomain.foo/$1/$2/$3    [L]
</ifModule>
```

This will redirect to the sub domain if the URL pattern matches the rule

> *id greater than 20 but less than 40*

If your main domain and sub domain have same URL pattern,

> http://maindomain.foo/en/30/article-on-codeigniter-routing

will automatically redirects to

> http://sub.maindomain.foo/en/30/article-on-codeigniter-routing

Comment: that code doesnt unfortunately seem to redirect anything...any ideas??

Comment: Yep because other bits in the .htaccess are still working.  I think it's because of the modification i made...(!).  Basically i had to change the url structure around.  Therefore old url structure is https://maindomain.com/en/39/Title but should redirect to https://sub.maindomain.com/tours/Title/en/39  where Title is $title, en is $lang and 39 is $id which is between 20 and 40...

Comment: Yes. that could be the reason. Try reordering the params as http://sub.maindomain.foo/tours/$3/$1/$2

Comment: yeah - that's what i had modified it to, but basically nothing happens.  The page still stays with the old url structure and no redirect occurs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166585/discussion-between-tom-chambers-and-praneeth-nidarshan).

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have same range of id like the subdomain, you can try this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "content";

$route['(.+)'] = function ( $params ){
                        $param = explode("/", $params);
                        if(20 >= (int) $param[1] =< 40){
                            return "subdomain";
                        }
                        else{
                            return "content/" . $param[0] . "/" . $param[1];
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: so does that mean i'd need a controller called subdomain?  can that just be a url instead e.g. https://subdomain.example.com/$param[0]/$param[1]    ?

Answer (score 2):

I might be being stupid here - but isn't the solution to amend your controller and do the following?

```
public function content($lang,$id){
    if ($id > 20 && $id < 40){
        $post = base64_encode(serialize($post));
        redirect('subdomain.domain.com/'.$lang.'/'.$id.'/'.$post);
    } else {
        // carry on processing ....
    }
}
```

I have amended my answer based on your query about posting data. I've serialized and base64 encoded it. To unserialize it you will need https://github.com/jqr/php-serialize (I am not a ruby expert so know nothing about this) and from research I believe you would need `Base64.decode64()` for the base64 decoding.

Comment: do you know if i can get the array of data in codigniter and THEN redirect to ruby subdomain and parse across the array?  would this just be a POST call or would the fact that one variable is php and the other ruby cause a prob???

Comment: I have amended my answer :)